# groff mom doesn't give a pdf output

Tags: groff

I am currently trying to learn the mom macro package from groff.
The problem is that whenever I compile the file to pdf:

```
groff -mom -Tpdf file.mom > file.pdf
```

The output, in Zathura, is an empty pdf.
Here is the sample input file:

```
.TITLE    "Stretched to the Breaking Point"
```

The same happens while using `-Tps` instead of the `-Tpdf` flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A document typeset with the `mom` macros needs to have a bit more setup than just defining the title.  In particular, it needs `.START`.  Defining the title of the document won't make it appear in the document.

This is a fairly minimal `mom` document:

```
.TITLE "Stretched to the Breaking Point"
.PRINTSTYLE     TYPESET
.PAPER          A4
.START
```

See e.g. the [`sample_docs.mom`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/contrib/mom/examples/sample_docs.mom) document distributed with `groff`.

Comment: Alright, I added all these, and fixed my compiler, now it's all working!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, the custom processing I made did not process the command the same way it was displayed:
What was actually processed was:
`groff -mom -Tpdf > file.pdf`, without the name of the input file.